# confused about .yarnrc and .npmrc

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a private npm registry and a `.npmrc` file in the root directory of my project like this

```
_auth=${NPM_TOKEN}
always-auth=true
email=example@gmail.com
registry=https://example.com/artifactory/api/npm/
```

But I use `yarn install` to install the packages. Now, I am confused.

Should I create a `.yarnrc` file? If so, how can I convert `.npmrc` above to `.yarnrc`? Didn't find configurations such as `_auth`, `always-auth` in https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarnrc/

`yarn` installs packages from `https://registry.yarnpkg.com`, `npm` installs packages from `https://registry.npmjs.org/`. They have different registries. I am not sure `yarn` can installs packages from my private npm registry and obey the configurations of `.npmrc`.

I am going to use `yarn`. Should I build a private yarn registry?

Comment: According to https://gemfury.com/help/private-yarn/, the npm config should work just fine. Yarn is built to be a drop-in replacement to npm so it uses the same configs/etc.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue. I just created `.yarnrc` file in the root folder of my project with the following content and it worked.

```
registry "<artifactory-url>"
```